# Android code, Activity.onTouchEvent Unknown Source

Tags: android

Hi have changed a Opencv example, to only add action when user touch the screen.
The code have tree class. FdActivity which extends Activity, FdViewBase which extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback , and finally FdView extends FdViewBase.

The onCreate method of FdActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);            
        setContentView(new FdView(this));        
      }
```

FdViewBase have in class constructor the method call 'setFocusable(true);' .
And finally onTouchEvent code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {                  
         //   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
              Log.i(TAG,"DOWN");                
            Log.i(TAG,"/\");
            return true;
        }
```

No compile or execute error happens with the code in this way, but if I uncomment the if statement, I get this error message:

```
04-16 21:59:06.011: I/OpenCV_NativeCamera(8952): ### Camera FPS ### [780] Frames, 12.84 FPS
    04-16 21:59:06.662: D/AndroidRuntime(8952): Shutting down VM
    04-16 21:59:06.662: W/dalvikvm(8952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity.onTouchEvent(Unknown Source)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2099)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1721)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2200)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1884)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    04-16 21:59:06.732: E/AndroidRuntime(8952):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-16 21:59:07.432: I/OpenCV_NativeCamera(8952): ### Camera FPS ### [810] Frames, 21.09 FPS
    04-16 21:59:08.864: I/OpenCV_NativeCamera(8952): ### Camera FPS ### [840] Frames, 21.00 FPS
    04-16 21:59:12.588: I/OpenCV_NativeCamera(8952): ### Camera FPS ### [870] Frames, 8.04 FPS
    04-16 21:59:13.168: I/Process(8952): Sending signal. PID: 8952 SIG: 9
```

I don't know why it's happing, it's appears that the event source isn't visible.

Eclipse didn't displayed any warning or error messages, no other error appears in LogCat.
So anybody knows whys it's happing?

Thanks =]

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(new FdView(this));
```

replace the above code as below

```
View view = new FdView(this);
view.setOnTouchListener(this);
setContentView(view);
```

This was because you were not setting ontouch to any view.

Comment: I rebuilded the project, after updating Eclipse, and the error was gone, but Eclipse started to display a warning about no view for listener. And this tip worked, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `false` from you onTouchEvent() listener.

When you return `true`, the event is not propagated further down the line, and might be causing the NPE.